# Data loss while inserting special characters to MySql blob

Tags: java, mysql, sql, blob

I'm tyring to insert data to MySql. The column is a blob varbinary.
My code is written in java and I'm using jdbc for connection.
The data that I'm trying to insert is an output of Encryption algorithm and it has random and awkward chars. When inserting some of the characters are changed. I found some guide that 
explains that the reason is to secure the DB from sql injection. 
I'm interested of inserting my data anyway. Is the there a way to it
without using prepareStatment?

Comment: Why do you want to do this `INSERT` without a prepared statement? Prepared statements are the best way to do this without any hassle

Comment: It will harm the generic functionality of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Its an encoding problem , try using utf8 for the encoding of your mySQL table.

Comment: Not Working. 10x though.

Comment: i tried every charset before posting the question. 
I also tried escape special chars. It is a MySql definition for fact that changes characters to protect from sql injection.